# Add key pair value to array

Tags: php

I have two arrays and want to add the values from the first array as a key-pair value to the second. So the key will say [topic] and the value being the value from the first array. I have provided the original arrays, as well as the results I am looking for. Thank you.

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 1
)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [first] => Michelle
        [last] => Walters
        [sun] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 182
        [first] => Robin
        [last] => Conti
        [sun] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 183
        [first] => Cheri
        [last] => Constantino-Shor
        [sun] => 1
    )
```

)

HERE IS THE RESULT I AM LOOKING FOR:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 1
)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [first] => Michelle
        [last] => Walters
        [sun] => 1
        [topic]=> 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 182
        [first] => Robin
        [last] => Conti
        [sun] => 1
        [topic]=> 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 183
        [first] => Cheri
        [last] => Constantino-Shor
        [sun] => 1
        [topic]=> 1
    )

)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how the to arrays relate.  Are teh values in teh first array related to the topic key in the sub-array to the second array?  Are the numerical keys between array 1 and array 2 the only relation?  Also, have you made any attempt at doing this yourself, as the solution here could be as simple as executing a for loop?

Comment: To whom may I address my invoice?

Comment: The first array is the array of values that will become the value for each `topic` key. This is a really really trivial question. Just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely straightforward - there are probably a million ways to do this - the most elementary being a `for` loop. Assuming your array of topic values is called `$topics` and your main array is called `$users`:

```
$topics = array(1, 2, 1);

$users = array(
    array(
        'id' => 19,
        'first' => 'Michelle',
        'last' => 'Walters',
        'sun' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 182,
        'first' => 'Robin',
        'last' => 'Conti',
        'sun' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 183,
        'first' => 'Cheri',
        'last' => 'Constantino-Shor',
    ),
);

$count = count($users);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $users[$i]['topic'] = $topics[$i];
}

var_dump($users);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 19
      'first' => string 'Michelle' (length=8)
      'last' => string 'Walters' (length=7)
      'sun' => int 1
      'topic' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 182
      'first' => string 'Robin' (length=5)
      'last' => string 'Conti' (length=5)
      'sun' => int 1
      'topic' => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 183
      'first' => string 'Cheri' (length=5)
      'last' => string 'Constantino-Shor' (length=16)
      'topic' => int 1
```